# NavigationDrawer not working correctly with SupportLibrary revision 21

Tags: java, android

I just updated my android SDK in order to get the android 5 updates. Those are the steps I did:

- Updated the android-SDK
- Updated the eclipse plugins
- Updated my project build target=21 and targetSdkVersion=21

Then I ran my app (wich uses the compat-v7 library) and found that the navigation drawer seems buggy. The app icon in the action bar is gone and the overall style seems incorrect (see the picture 2).

So I took the ["Creating a Navigation Drawer"](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) example and performed the following test:

Downloaded the sample project, updated the build target and targetSdk and replaced the android-support-v4.jar with the Compat-v7 library (revision 21) .
Changed the ActionBarDrawerToggle import from `android.support.v4...` to `import android.support.v7...`

The result is correct:

**Picture 1:**

[image]

Then I try to swap the MainActivity parent class from Activity to ActionBarActivity, changing `getActionBar()` calls with `getSupportActionBar()` and `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Also added the `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` theme to the activity

It works but the app icon is missing and the options menu are not shown as an action. See screenshots below.

**Picture 2:**

[image]

How can I fix it?

**UPDATES**:

With the code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

You get the following bar:

[image]

It is pretty ok but I preffer the compact version, where the drawer indicator/ arrow have no padding with the icon (see image below). How can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: I have got the same issue with the toolbar eating up my menu options and putting them in the overflow menu:/ Have you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the intended behavior for the new Material Design paradigm. According to the official documentation on [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

> In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

**UPDATE:**
You can find the answer for your second question here:

[How to change Toolbar navigation icon and options menu margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26809133/how-to-change-toolbar-navigation-icon-and-options-menu-margin)

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended, the app icon is not displayed by default now. You can call the following to display the icon again.

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: The "Creating a Navigation Drawer" example already uses it and the icon is still missing

Comment: This is not working, better solution is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26716012/1159404

Answer (score 0):

After you switch to new ActionBarActivity, it looks like it hides home/Logo of Actionbar. And the @style/Theme.AppCompat has not Logo by default. You can enable it with .setHomeButtonEnabled(true);