# Action bar app icon missing with Android 5

Tags: android

Just rebuilt my app using the Android 5 SDK and associated appcompat.

Seems to work fine but my app icon is no longer showing in top left hand corner. The icon to open nav drawer is there but no icon.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506266/navigationdrawer-not-working-correctly-with-supportlibrary-revision-21/26508114#26508114

Comment: You shouldn't have this icon on newer devices (per the docs) - see my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Use the code below in onCreate:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

I too noticed that the default projects created by Android Studio were missing the icon in the action bar. Here's how I fixed it.

Disclaimer: This solution will result in in the Material theme being dropped in favor of the older JellyBean/Kitkat styles.

First, change themes setting in styles.xml from this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

To this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Now change all your Activities to inherit from android.app.Activity instead of android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.  That is:

Change this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActivityBarActivity {
```

To this:

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

The end of result of doing this is an app that has the Holo theme more commonly seen on Jelly Bean and Kitkat.

Comment: Sorry, this is a bad suggestion, you are replacing the "Material" theme with the "Holo" theme, and this will have negative effects on the overall look of you app.

Comment: @Booger - Sorry you find my answer to be unsatisfactory. But I dispute that adopting the JellyBean/Kitkat "Holo" style is a "negative effect". I don't recall any problems last year when I shipped an app for JellyBean/Kitkat without the Material style.

Comment: @Booger - After taking several months off from Android development, I wanted to return, but using the latest tools. I gave myself a refresh course by going through the tutorial in the Big Nerd Ranch book.  The problem was that it became difficult to use Android Studio while following along with the code examples in the BNRG book. The Material theme didn't look the same as the book and the support.v7 Activity resulted in having to write different code that what was in the book. Hence, just for the sake of re-learning from the same book, I needed to stay on Holo.

Comment: The problem is the look of the app.  Generally you would want the latest UI elements (that are provided in Material, and the SupportLib).  You are bypassing all this by sticking with the "Old" style.  This will work perfectly fine (no bugs, etc) but will look non-modern, and will not take advantage of the newest Material design concepts.  Holo was released 5 years ago, you should be using Material.

Comment: @Booger - "look of the app" and "should be using Material" are both opinions. Not bad opinions, but it's not a requirement either.  The goal of my answer is to not steer people away from Material, but to help those coming from the old tool chain to see the same behavior as they are used to getting.  I suspect we're at a stand still on this.

Comment: Well I removed my down-vote based on your explanation, but still really think this is NOT a good suggestion ("holo" is not a good approach for current Android).  Peace, and thanks for the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to extend ActionBarActivity rather than Activity. And add the following code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have an icon in an API OS 5+ app. By default it is not displayed (and this is the preferred behavior). The Toolbar docs specifically state this:

"In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. *The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.*"

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html