# Action bar app icon missing with Android 5 in Mono.android

Tags: android, mono, icons

How to Implement Action bar app icon missing with Android 5 in mono.android and I have already used

this link **[Action bar app icon missing with Android 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525699/action-bar-app-icon-missing-with-android-5)**

but its not working.

Comment: Hi, what is your app style declared in manifest?
Please also show menu xml file for this activity please.

Comment: Manifest.xml file is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:debuggable="true" android:installLocation="auto" android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" package="net.awarebase.Test" android:versionName="0.0.1.0" android:versionCode="36">
 <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
 <application android:label="Test" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"></application>
 <activity android:name="Test.Android.Screens.LoginActivity" android:noHistory="true"></activity> 
</manifest>

Comment: Menu xml file is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:id="@+id/actionUpload"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_upload"
       android:showAsAction="always"
       android:title=""/>
    </item>
 </menu>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we using android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light" it will reflect the action bar title color and it will working fine if we use like:
android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo"

Answer (score 0):

I do not see "application" tag in your manifest.

I have it like this:

```
<manifest...

<application android:label="myApplication" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_main" android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light"></application>

</manifest>
```

Please check if you have android:theme declared in your manifest.
For my application it is: Theme.Holo.Light

Comment: How to change action bar title color when i am using theme "android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light"