# How to change Toolbar navigation icon and options menu margin

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu, android-toolbar

Is there any way to change the left margin of the Navigation icon and the right margin of the Action items in `Toolbar`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I went through the `Toolbar` source code to find a solution and it turned out to be pretty simple.

Toolbar uses two styles to style the toolbar and the navigation icon. Just had to override those styles with my own.

```
<style name="myToolbarNavigationButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
</style>

<style name="myToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/myToolbarStyle</item>
    <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/myToolbarNavigationButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Does anyone have a github repository they can point to that leverages this solution? I've tried numerous things at this point, including this solution. None of them seem to work for me. A full working project that could be shared would be very helpful.

Comment: @EricSchlenz Ok. I'll create one.

Comment: @ShubhadeepChaudhuri : This is not working for me. Do you have any idea? Please help me.

Comment: This get's rid of my actionbar buttons and makes the single navigation button the whole width of my toolbar, any ideas?