# logo/icon is missing when using Theme.Material.Light

Tags: android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme

I have to customize my app to the new Material design, but it looks like Android dropping the icon in the action bar at the left corner. I can't just drop my brand icon.
Is there any way to add it? I'm using the following style in the values-v21 in res folder for Android 5.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
```

ok i figured that out, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506266/navigationdrawer-not-working-correctly-with-supportlibrary-revision-21/26508114#26508114)
all you have to do is:

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
ab.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Theme.Material.Light this theme doesn't support showing App icon in actionbar.